# round down and up in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to know how to round up and down between in a range example:

```
57272.726 ---> 57272.730
57272.724--> 57272.720
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: sqlserver 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

**Round Up:-**

```
declare @value decimal(10,2)
set @value=57272.726

SELECT CAST(ROUND(@value, 2) AS NUMERIC(12,3)) As RoundUpValues
```

**Round Down:-**

```
declare @value decimal(10,2)
set @value=57272.724

SELECT CAST(ROUND(@value, 2) AS NUMERIC(12,3)) As RoundDownValues
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select round(57272.726);
```

Output : 57273

Syntax:

```
Select round(X,D);
```

> `X`: The argument or the number you want to round
>
> `D`: The no.of Decimal places you want to round(If you have not specified it, it is taken as zero)

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

The following query may help you getting the desirable result.

Select ROUND( number, decimal_places [, operation ] )

SELECT round(57272.724, 2);

It gives 57272.72 as answer. 
It gets round down because last decimal digit is 4 which is in the range 0.1 to 0.4

SELECT round(57272.726, 2);

It gives 57272.73 as answer.
It gets round up because last decimal digit is 6 which is in the range 0.5 to 0.9

Comment: thank you.this query show follow result for me:
57272.730.and rounding up for any numbers.

Comment: I have added a new link , please check to  know about rounding down operation.

Comment: I try rounding but result is not true.all example rounding to Up.i want if third number after point between .1 and .4 round Down.if between .5 and .9  round Up

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT ROUND(57272.726 , 2);
```

Return : `57272.730`.

```
SELECT ROUND(57272.724 , 2);
```

return : `57272.720`.